# One Assembly book critique

Tags: ecclesiology

I’m looking for critiques or rebuttal to the ecclesiology concept presented in this book: [One Assembly: Rethinking the Multisite and Multiservice Church Models (9Marks)](https://a.co/d/9VKLwfk).

Comment: Welcome to the Christianity Stack Exchange site.  I don't think that asking for a book critique is "allowed" - please take our Tour to find out what sort of questions about Christianity are welcome, and what sort of questions to avoid: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Welcome to C.SE.  One way to make your question work for this site is to ask a **denomination's view** of the book's **thesis** on ecclesiology (rather than the more general "book critique" question), which you need to provide (in summary) in the Question text itself, rather than simply pointing to the book, by [editing the question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/posts/97320/edit).  That way a potential answerer doesn't have to read the book.  You also need to specify the denomination / theological perspective in the Q as well as in tags.